# Permission denied after allowing read and write permissions in manifest and runtime

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error

```
   W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181116_172404.jpg (Permission denied)
```

I added the following in my manifests:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Added following code in MainActivity.java

```
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    private void checkIfPermissionGranted() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int hasWritePermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int hasReadPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if(hasWritePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }
            if(hasReadPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

How do I fix this? Here's a screenshot of app permissions in settings menu

[image]

Comment: `/root/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181116_172404.jpg` is not likely to be a valid filesystem path. Where did you get this? In particular, where is that `/root` part coming from?

Comment: It came from a file explorer called Cx Explorer, I want to store selected files through an intent in a zip file and I needed the whole path which the default file explorer is not giving. Using default file explorer, it also gives the same exception but this time it is 

        (No Such file or Directory)

Comment: "I want to store selected files through an intent in a zip file and I needed the whole path which the default file explorer is not giving" -- that is because Android supports more than just files on the filesystem. In fact, filesystem access continues to fade away, with that process accelerating on Android Q and R. "It came from a file explorer called Cx Explorer" -- then you will need to contact the developers of this app and ask why they are providing you with invalid paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Implement this overide method..

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) 
{

        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


    //  implement Your File related Code here,

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is Require for Access External Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```